# Pull a branch of a "podified" project on github

Tags: git, github, magicalrecord, cocoapods

I would like to pull a branch of a github project instead of the master. Somebody know how to do it without being obliged to fork the master and merge the branch with the master on my own  ?

pod 'MagicalRecord', :git => 'https://github.com/nhenin/MagicalRecord.git'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [docs on the Wiki](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/wiki/Dependency-declaration-options), it has some extra options for you such as picking a specific commit.

Answer (score 3):

[This pull request](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/262) made this possible. Documentation does not seem to be up-to-date though.

Here is how to do it:

```
pod 'JSFooBar', :git => 'https://github.com/joelso/JSFooBar.git', :branch => 'develop'
```